# FilterGetMessage is error?

Tags: c#, service, driver, minifilter

I am writing windows service to communication with minifilter (kernel).

1. Using **FltSendMessage** in minifilter
2. Using **FilterGetMessage** in service

The status of **FilterGetMessage** is success (status = 0). But the buffer is always null. **What is not correct?**

**This is my code in minifilter: C++ code**

```
status = FltSendMessage(
                gFilterHandle,
                &gClientPort, 
                (PVOID)FltObjects->FileObject->FileName.Buffer,
                FltObjects->FileObject->FileName.MaximumLength,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL);
```

p/s: above code is put PreCreate callback

**This is my code in service: C# code**

```
// Constant buffer size
public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

// message header struct
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER {
        public uint replyLength;
        public ulong messageId;
}

// message receive struct
public struct DATA_RECEIVE
{
        public FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER messageHeader;
        public byte[] messageContent;
}

DATA_RECEIVE dataReceive = new DATA_RECEIVE();
dataReceive.messageContent = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

int headerSize = Marshal.SizeOf(dataReceive.messageHeader);
int dataSize = BUFFER_SIZE + headerSize;

status = FilterGetMessage(hPort, out dataReceive.messageHeader, dataSize, IntPtr.Zero);
```

**UPDATE:** Although, status is success, the value of message header is 0

```
 1. dataReceive.messageHeader.messageId = 0

 2. dataReceive.messageHeader.replyLength = 0
```

**UPDATE ANSWER:**

```
 1. Update old code:

// message receive struct
public struct DATA_RECEIVE
{
        public FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER messageHeader;
        public fixed byte messageContent[BUFFER_SIZE];
}
```

And:

```
// Get data size
int dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(dataReceive);
```

2. Add new code: After use `FilterGetMessage` function

   // Check status and get content message

   ```
   int status = FilterGetMessage(hPort, out dataReceive.messageHeader, dataSize, IntPtr.Zero);

   if (status == 0)
   {
      int index = 0;
      unsafe
      {
         byte* ptr = dataReceive.messageContent;
         for (; *ptr != 0; ptr += 2)
         {
              messageContent[index++] = *ptr;
         }
      };
      filePath = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageContent);
   }
   ```

Comment: A note: you can access `dataReceive.messageContent` like a normal array, no need to use pointers like that!

Comment: I couldn't use **filePath = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataReceive.messageContent)**. So I used pointer.

Comment: From the look of what you are doing there, are you sure it's ASCII?

Comment: **dataReceive.messageContent** it is wide-character (1 character/2 bytes). This is received from driver (kenerl) And I send a buffer of UNICODE_STRING

Comment: Use `Encoding.Unicode`..!

Comment: I tested with `Encoding.Unicode`, It cannot convert to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see one problem right away with this code:

```
public struct DATA_RECEIVE
{
    public FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER messageHeader;
    public byte[] messageContent;
}
```

This does not create a continuous struct. This will create a struct with one `FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER` and one reference to an array (which is not what the function expects). A `byte[]` is a reference, so the array data is not in the struct. If you try `Marshal.SizeOf` on the struct, you'll get 16 or 20 bytes, not `sizeof( FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER ) + the length of the buffer`. What you need here is to use unsafe code with a fixed buffer:

```
public unsafe struct DATA_RECEIVE
{
    public FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER messageHeader;
    public fixed byte messageContent[BUFFER_SIZE];
}
```

That will create a continuous struct, with the array data in the struct itself instead of somewhere else. Try this and verify the final size with `Marshal.SizeOf`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris so much. I could get the content message.