# How to get content of message from driver (kernel)?

Tags: c#, windows-services, driver, minifilter

I try to use windows service (`C# code`) to communicate with minifilter driver (`kernel`).

1. Using `FltSendMessage` to send message from driver to service
2. Using `FilterGetMessage` to get message to driver from service
3. I try to send a string (filename such as `"D:\\folder\\text.txt"`).
   But the `FilterGetMessage`'s parameter don't contain message's
   content.

**Question: How Can I get message content from driver to service?**

**UPDATE 1**:

4. [`FltSendMessage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
5. [`FilterGetMessage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
6. [Communication Between User Mode and Kernel Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**UPDATE 2**

7. I use the functions like this
   [FilterGetMessage is error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860735/filtergetmessage-is-error).
8. But I don't know the next step to get message's content

**UPDATE 3: ANSWER** at [FilterGetMessage is error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860735/filtergetmessage-is-error)

Comment: You'll need to show us some documentation on those functions.

Comment: Ok good, so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Chris Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860735/filtergetmessage-is-error.